# How to get admin dashboard widgets?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to replace my default wordpress admin dashboard. How can I get all dashboard widgets?

[Dashboard Widgets API Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Getting_Widget_Options) explains to use get_option. But this option doesn't exist in my case (so it just returns `(bool) false` - I'm confused.

```
get_option( 'dashboard_widget_options' )
```

What I basically want to get is the content + tile of each widget to build my own overview of widgets.